# React native vector incons issue

Tags: reactjs, vector, icons, native

I spend a lot of time to fix this problem, but couldn't find a solution for this. Pease 
need your help on how to get icon from react vector icons. Below my code and 
package.json file. I just want to add a menu icon to the nav bar... Thanks for the help

```
import React from 'react';
   import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
   // import {FiMenu} from 'react-icons/fi';
   //import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
   import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/';
   const MenuNav = ({navigation}) => {
     const showDrawer = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
   };



 return (
    <View style={styles.menucontainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.img} onPress={showDrawer}>
        <Image source={require('../imgs/menu.png')} />
        <Icon
          name="check"
          color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
          size={25}
          type="entypo"
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Menu</Text>
    </View>
    );
   };



 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
   },
```

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to 
export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up 
default

and named imports.

Comment: I think ```@material-ui/*``` are not compatible with RN projects, only with ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `Icon` the wrong way.

In `react-native-vector-icons` you should do it this way:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons'
// and replace SimpleLineIcons with the set of icons you want to use
```

Here you have [full list of the sets](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did used that way previously and there was an error:

Comment: Unrecognized font family 'simple-line-icons'

Comment: Yes, that's a common error. You have to link the library first, in some cases even add the fonts manualy to Xcode. They have a full tutorial about it [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: Almost forgot, you need to recompile the app after linking the library. And it will work after that.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I tried to avoid the xcode but it didn't happened. It works now